# Product topology and subspace topology

Tags: general-topology, product-space

This seems to be a basic question but I can't get a proof.

> Suppose $X\times Y$ is the product space of non-empty topological spaces $(X, \tau)$ and $(Y, \rho)$. Let $\tau'$ and $\rho'$ be the subspace topologies of $X$ and $Y$, derived from the product topology through the inclusion maps $\iota_1: X\to X\times Y$ and $\iota_2: Y\to X\times Y$, respectively. Is it always true $\tau'=\tau$ and $\rho'=\rho$?

> If there are infinitely many, of arbitrary infinite cardinality, factor spaces, does the above still hold?

If the above is indeed true, can we then think of this as the defining property for product topology? That is, suppose we start from an arbitrary topology $\eta$ on the set $X\times Y$, and equip $X$ and $Y$ with subspace topologies $\eta|_X$ and $\eta|_Y$, derived from $\eta$ through the inclusion maps $\iota_1$ and $\iota_2$, respectively. Is it not necessarily true that $\eta= \eta|_X \times \eta|_Y$?

This question was motivated by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4640215/416552). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Subspace topology and product topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3030041/subspace-topology-and-product-topology) Your question is a little different but the answer is the same.

Comment: @AnneBauval The question is essentially the same, but I want a proof, rather than only a conclusion.

Comment: There can be no proof since the answer is that the question does not really make sense.

Comment: In other words, if you want a counter-example, take $Y=\emptyset$ and $X$ nonempty. Then $X\times Y$ is empty so you can't have the desired inclusion embedding to retrieve the topology on $X$. But the statement is indeed correct when neither is empty. Choose $y\in Y$ and $x\in X$. Then $X\times\{y\}$ is homeomorphic to $X$ and $\{x\}\times Y$ is homeomorphic to $Y$. So taking the appropriate embeddings retrieves the topologies of $X$ and $Y$, and in particular retrieves the topology of $X\times Y$.

Comment: Thanks, @Frousse! So the crucial thing here is that neither of $X$ or $Y$, when non-empty, is really a subspace of Cartesian product $X\times Y$. So to properly define the inclusion maps is the key. I'll write up a correct statement and its proof based on this realization.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment by @Frousse, the correct statement should be as the following.

> Proposition. Let $(X_\alpha, \tau_\alpha)_{\alpha\in A}$ be a family of non-empty topological spaces with index set $A$, and $X:=\prod_{\alpha\in A}X_\alpha$ the product space with the product topology $\tau$ and projection maps $\pi_\alpha: X\to X_\alpha$. Fix $\hat{x}:=\left(\hat{x_\alpha}\right)_\alpha\in X$, where $\hat{x_{\alpha}}\in X_{\alpha}$ for all $\alpha\in A$, and define corresponding inclusion maps $\iota_{\alpha, \hat{x}}: X_\alpha \to X$ such that $\left(\pi_{\beta}\circ\iota_{\alpha, \hat{x}}\right)(x_\alpha)=\begin{cases}\hat{x_{\beta}},& \quad \beta\neq \alpha\\ x_\alpha,& \quad \alpha=\beta \end{cases}$. If equipping each image $Y_{\alpha, \hat{x}}:=\iota_{\alpha, \hat{x}}\left(X_\alpha\right)\subset X$ with their subspace topology $\tau|_{Y_{\alpha, \hat{x}}}$ respectively, then $\tau\simeq\prod_{\alpha\in A}\tau|_{Y_{\alpha, \hat{x}}}$.

The proof requires a basic lemma.

> Lemma. A net (sequence) $(x_i)_{i\in I}$ converges in the product space $X=\prod_{\alpha\in A}X_\alpha$ iff the component nets $\left(\pi_{\alpha}(x_i)\right)_{i\in I}$ converges in $X_\alpha$ for all $\alpha\in A$, where $\pi_\alpha: X\to X_\alpha$ are the set-theoretic projections. (That is, product topology is the topology of component-wise convergence. A proof can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2107024/416552).)

*Proof of proposition.* It suffices to show every inclusion $\iota_{\alpha, \hat{x}}: X_\alpha\to Y_{\alpha, \hat{x}}$ is a homeomorphism.

Let $U_\alpha$ be an open set in $X_\alpha$, then $\pi_\alpha^{-1}(U_\alpha)$ is open in the product space $X$, and so its image $\iota_{\alpha, \hat{x}}(U_\alpha)=Y_{\alpha, \hat{x}}\cap \pi_\alpha^{-1}(U_\alpha)$ is open under the subspace topology of $Y_{\alpha, \hat{x}}$.

Conversely, let a net $(x_\alpha^i)_{i\in I}\to \xi_\alpha$ converge in $X_\alpha$, we want to show net convergence $\iota_{\alpha, \hat{x}}(x_\alpha^i)_{i\in I}\to \iota_{\alpha, \hat{x}}(\xi_\alpha)$ in $Y_{\alpha, \hat{x}}$, which is a subset of product space $X$. By the lemma above, it suffices to show net convergence $\left(\pi_{\beta}\circ\iota_{\alpha, \hat{x}}\right)(x_\alpha^i)_{i\in I}\to \left(\pi_{\beta}\circ\iota_{\alpha, \hat{x}}\right)(\xi_\alpha)$ in $X_\beta$, for every $\beta\in A$. This is trivially true by the definition of inclusion map $\iota_{\alpha, \hat{x}}$ in the proposition.

Comment: I don't think your proof is correct, in general $\pi_\alpha(V_\alpha')$ could be bigger than $\iota_{\alpha, \hat{x}}^{-1}(V_\alpha)$. You also shouldn't need that the projections are open. To check that $\iota_{\alpha, \hat{x}}$ is continuous it's enough to check that each coordinate (ie $\pi_\beta \circ \iota_{\alpha, \hat{x}}$) is continuous, and these are either constant or identity.

Comment: I think you are right. However, may I ask why, from $\pi_\beta \circ \iota_{\alpha, \hat{x}}$ being constant or identity, we can conclude $\iota_{\alpha, \hat{x}}$ is cts?

Comment: A quite useful fact about the product topology is that a map $f : Z \to \prod X_\alpha$ is continuous iff each $\pi_\alpha \circ f$ is continuous. In fact this is an alternative definition of the product topology. I recommend you either prove it yourself or find it in whatever source you learned about the product topology from.

Comment: @ronno Thanks! I'll update my proof.